# I can't find a proper sample for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, reactiveui

I'm having difficult finding a tutorial/sample, or even an empty "skeleton" solution of creating a **Xamarin Forms** cross-platform solution for **iOS/Android/UWP** using **ReactiveUI** + **ReactiveUI.XamForms**.

Has anyone stumbled on one lately? Just something to get me started in the right direction in learning/practicing ReacitiveUI on Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this the other day

https://github.com/PureWeen/ReactiveUI.XamlForms.Sample

Whether it's best practices or not is debatable :-)

But it should hopefully help you get started

Comment: You made this from scratch or were you able to find a base project?

Comment: By the way, thanks for the quick response!  Your sample looks great.

Comment: A lot of the core ideas came from this sample https://github.com/paulcbetts/XamarinEvolve2014 here and then i just changed some things based on my experiences in my own app. For example the Akavache stuff I have in there came from this conversation https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/984  . Other things like how I changed the AppBootstrapper serialization are just what I found to work.

Comment: Also on an unfortunate side note one thing to keep in mind with ReactiveLists  https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/806 https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31415 as they relate to Xamarin Forms things :-/  I've started using DynamicData for most of my lists that I bind out into Xamarin Forms things. Plan is to make a note of that in the sample at some point :-)

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/TheEightBot/Reactive-Examples and the guest lecture at Xamarin University and also https://github.com/kentcb/WorkoutWotch and Kent's video series (see previous link)